# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_PyUnicode_Type", referenced from: when using python_boost

Tags: python, c++, gcc, boost-python

My environment is using Anaconda/Python 3.7.9 on Mac OSX Catalina.

I have installed boost_python for `conda boost`

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const * doYouDo( const char* jobs ){
    return "Hello, I am an embedded engineer.";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( what ){
    boost::python::def( "doYouDo", doYouDo);
}
```

then compile with this.

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -I/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/include/boost/python/ -I/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/include/python3.7m/ -lboost_python37 -shared -o whatModule.so what.cpp
```

I got this error below.

```
In file included from what.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/python.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/python/exception_translator.hpp:10:
/usr/local/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: warning: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use
      <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [-W#pragma-messages]
BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/pragma_message.hpp:24:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE'
# define BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(x) _Pragma(BOOST_STRINGIZE(message(x)))
                                 ^
<scratch space>:2:2: note: expanded from here
 message("The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) " "in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use " "<boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace bo...
 ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyUnicode_Type", referenced from:
      boost::python::to_python_value<char const* const&>::get_pytype() const in what-7927a1.o
  "__Py_NoneStruct", referenced from:
      boost::python::api::object::object() in what-7927a1.o
      boost::python::converter::pointer_arg_from_python<char const*>::pointer_arg_from_python(_object*) in what-7927a1.o
      boost::python::converter::pointer_arg_from_python<char const*>::operator()() const in what-7927a1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess it says there is no `_PyUnicode_Type`,`__Py_NoneStruct`

However which library has them?? Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thank you very much, but it might too general. I have an idea why this happen but, I am not sure where `_PyUnicode_Type` and `__Py_NoneStruct` and want to know someone has same problem with `boost_python`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved with `python-config --ldflags`

My final gcc command is below. `aiwave` is my anacond env name

```
$export LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/lib/
$g++ -fPIC -Wall -I/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/include/boost/python/ -I/Users/whitebear/anaconda3/envs/aiwave/include/python3.7m/ `python-config --ldflags` -lboost_python37 -shared -o whatModule.so what.cpp
```

Additional information

my python-config is 2.7 but it works somehow

```
$python-config --ldflags
-L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

Comment: Depending on your brew setup, you may need to run ``python3-config --ldflags`` instead. The first command gave ``python2`` libraries where I needed the V3 versions.